# overheating and not booting

Tags: boot-issues

I left the pi 2 compressing a huge file for about 18 hours and now it's overheating and not booting (I don't know if that's the cause btw). I had connected a device up to the 5v rail on the pi that used about 0.5 amps.There was also a drive connected but it was externally powered. Now when I connect it the raspberry pi alone without booting into an OS it uses 1.27 amps and heats up very fast. In about 2 seconds the SoC is untouchable. The 3.3V line is 2.15 volts, but the SoC is still overheating. The red led is always off and the green one does flicker even if I have a bootable SD 
Please help

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker! (Read: it's most likely dead. Though it might be interesting to figure out what happend. Try to power it with the SD card removed and repeat your measurements. The 3V3 rail at 2.15V is certainly not a good sign.)

Comment: You could leave it for a few days in the hopes it is just the main [polyfuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse) -- but I doubt that is the issue, since if it were it would probably not go on at all.

Comment: yes, the SoC is most likely mostly dead. When i power the 3.3V line it takes .9A and the SoC is the one heating up like crazy :/   such a shame i had a very neat backup system setup with this :/

Comment: and btw all of the measurments where done without an sd card because i didn't want to risk destroying it